# Can I check if Firebase ValueEventListener onDataChanged was already called?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to determine if `onDataChanged()` was already called?
It's weird that I don't know if I have to replace my data or inflate for the first time.

I have only came up to this solution:

```
    mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

          boolean wasCalled = false;

          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               if (wasCalled) {
                      // do something
               } else {
                      // do something else
               }
               wasCalled = true;
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          }
    });
```

But wondering if there is better solution.

Comment: That seems correct to me. Is something not working about it?